# What is the rms velocity of these 4 gas molecules?

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, physics

Q) Velocity of 4 gas molecules are respectively 4m/s, 6m/s, 7m/s and 9m/s. What will be their rms velocity?

(a) $\sqrt{45.5} ms^{-1}$

(b) $52m^2s^{-2}$

(c) $45.5ms^{-1}$

(d) $45.5m^2s^{-2}$

**My attempt:**

$$\sqrt{\frac{4^2+6^2+7^2+9^2}{4}}$$

$$=\sqrt{45.5} ms^{-1}$$

So, (a) should be the answer. However, the answer sheet says that the answer is (d).

[image]

Aren't they wrong?

Comment: Yes, even the units are wrong on answer d.

Comment: There's something wrong. The stated solution does not agrees with the question. You're asked what's the rms velocity, but the solution gives the average square velocity